# Meteor js - Function declaration vs Function expression in another file

Tags: javascript, meteor

In meteor js:

```
// In: server/lib/utils.js
    function foo() {
        return 'bad'
    }

    bar = function() {
        return 'good'
    }

    // In: server/server.js
    part(of(a(larger(computation(foo())))))
    bar()
```

Calling foo results in a runtime error: `foo is not defined`.

Calling bar does not.

Why? Also, is there a better way group functions rather than just having a file with a bunch of function expressions bounded to global variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats because when you declare `bar = function(){}` you are making it a global scoope function, and thats why you can access is from whatever server js file.

and `function foo(){}` is not a global function.

Comment: Could you elaborate why `function foo(){}` isn't global?

Comment: @wie yes but the docs say it best [namespacing](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/namespacing)